# Why does apache2.2 keeps installing instead of apache2.4?

Tags: apache, vagrant

I've been trying to set **Vagrant** up for local development on my machine. I see from [Apache's official](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) website that 2.4.7 is the current stable version. And I had no issues installing it on my VPS. But with Vagrant it's a different story. I'm trying with both Base64 and Base32 boxes. This is the command i'm running:

`sudo apt-get install -y apache2`

It should install apache 2.4.x. But it doesn't. Sometimes it installs version 2.2, sometimes 2.4. This is driving me nuts, since the whole idea of using Vagrant is to have the same Virtual machine replicated everywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Debian based distro (possibly Ubuntu) you're using is still using 2.2.x.  Switching to 2.4.x from 2.2.x means all the 3rd party modules they ship have to be upgraded (or at least rebuilt) so they probably haven't made the switch yet.

Comment: Thank you for answering. How would you explain the fact that it does sometimes in fact install the 2.4 version?